# Python 3 - Hex-String to bytes

Tags: python

I am using python 3 and try to convert a hex-string to a byte-represented form. So i used the following command:

```
bytes.fromhex('97ad300414b64c')
```

I Expected results like this: `b'\x97\xad\x30\x04\x14\xb6\x4c''` but got `b'\x97\xad0\x04\x14\xb6L'`. I am note sure what i am doing wrong, but maybe it is something with the encoding?

Comment: Everything is fine. The `print` function tries to make things 'look' friendly. And doesn't in this case. `print(bytes.fromhex('4d65727279204368726973746d6173'))`

Comment: `print(repr(b"\x30"))`

Comment: Some of the bytes correspond to printable characters. `\x30` => `'0'` and `\x4c` => `'L'`.

Comment: Thanks! Should have thought more about this before.

Comment: (both are confusion about the representation of `bytes` in Python 3 after converting from hex string.)

Comment: as you said: my main problem was the interpretation of the output representation. The answer in your suggestion clears this up. (Using `binascii.hexlify`) is what i needed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @user8651755 in the comments, this is due to the fact that some bytes correspond to printable characters. So the answer is: you are doing everything right.