# Convert string byte to byte like b'\x00\x01\x02'

Tags: python

I have a string of bytes like this:

```
mystring = '000102'
```

And I need:

```
result = b'\x00\x01\x02'
```

Now I did:

```
# Opt 1
result = bytearray(mystring, 'utf-8') # I suppose is not correct encoded
# Opt 2
result  = mystring.encode()
```

And both give me, `b'000102'`. How can I obtain the `'\x'` that defines every byte?

Thank you very much, I suposes is an easy question, but I can't find how do it

Comment: [Python 3 - Hex-String to bytes - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996767/python-3-hex-string-to-bytes) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create python bytes object from long hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443967/how-to-create-python-bytes-object-from-long-hex-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bytes fromhex [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex)

```
mystring = '000102'
y = bytes.fromhex(mystring)
print(y)
```

output:

```
b'\x00\x01\x02'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```py
my_string = "012345"

result = b""

for i in range(len(my_string)//2):
    b += bytes(chr(int(my_string[i:i+1],16)),encoding="ASCII")
```